# rsyslog - Avoid pushing certain logs to /var/log/messages

Tags: rsyslog

I'm having an ec2 linux server, and am tracking the logs of my application server using rsyslog so that I can push these logs to loggly.

The problem is, rsyslog is also logging these in /var/log/messages which I don't want. Is there any way to avoid this? Can I filter out certain messages in /etc/rsyslog.conf so that these are not pushed to var/log/messages?

****** UPDATE *******

I tried adding the following lines in rsyslog.conf:

```
if $programname == 'programName' then {
*.err                                                 /var/log/messages
} else {
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
}
```

However, upon restarting rsyslog, I see the following error:

```
Dec 11 08:01:46 <hostname> rsyslogd: the last error occured in /etc/rsyslog.conf, line 37:"if $programname == 'programName' then {"
Dec 11 08:01:46 <hostname> rsyslogd: warning: selector line without actions will be discarded
Dec 11 08:01:46 <hostname> rsyslogd-3000: unknown priority name "" [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/3000 ]
Dec 11 08:01:46 <hostname> rsyslogd: the last error occured in /etc/rsyslog.conf, line 39:"} else {"
Dec 11 08:01:46 <hostname> rsyslogd: warning: selector line without actions will be discarded
Dec 11 08:01:46 <hostname> rsyslogd-3000: unknown priority name "" [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/3000 ]
Dec 11 08:01:46 <hostname> rsyslogd: the last error occured in /etc/rsyslog.conf, line 41:"}"
Dec 11 08:01:46 <hostname> rsyslogd: warning: selector line without actions will be discarded
```

I suppose my version of rsyslog (5.8.10) doesn't support if / else. Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

first send the message to the file that you want.
then use `stop` to prevent further actions.

```
if $programname == 'apache2' then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log" name="action-omfile-apache2-rewrite")
    stop
}
```